# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance with django REST and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an API endpoint made from *Django Rest Framework* and I use Vue.js to display it in front-end.

I use a `api.service.js` to fetch the data:

```
import { CSRF_TOKEN } from "./csrf_token.js"
function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.status === 204) {
    return '';
  } else if (response.status === 404) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return response.json();
  }  
}
function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
  const config = {
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
          .then(handleResponse)
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
export { apiService };
```

So far there is my `Home.vue` where I want to display the data from my API (restaurants reviews):

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="container">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { apiService } from "@/common/api.service.js"
export default {
  name: "home",
  data () {
    return {
      reviews: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getReviews() {
      let endpoint = "/api/restaurant_review/";
      apiService(endpoint)
        .then(data => {
          this.reviews.push(...data.results)
      })
    }
  },
  created() {      
    this.getReviews()
    console.log(this.reviews)
    }  
};
</script>
```

I know my API works fine because I checked it with Django Browsable API:

[image]

So I did a `console.log()` with the data was correctly fetched but I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

So basically I can't spread my API array into `reviews`, that is also an array, how can I fix it?

When I do a console.log(data):

[image]

Comment: how does `data.results` look when you log it?

Comment: ```
[__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

Comment: it looks like an empty array

Comment: Sorry ```data.results``` give me 'undefined'

Comment: ok so the `undefined` is non-iterable, what about `console.log(data)`

Comment: The response payload returned from your API is an array and not an object.

Comment: With console.log(data) check my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `data` returned from the API doesn't have a property called `results` which is undefined when you try to spread it (only arrays and object support that spread operator), so you should do :

```
 this.reviews.push(...data)
```